# Props Error While sending Image uri to another Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-typescript

i am Getting this error while i am passing image uri to Another screnn

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.imageuri')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are passing the params to another screen then we can get it as below:

```
const params = this.props.route.params
const imageUri = params?.imageUri // prevent bug if imageUri not avaiable
```